# How can I invite myself to a server my discord bot is in?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I would like to find a way to generate an invite link that would be sent to my account for each server my bot is in. I can't figure out how I would do this though. I have a list of every server my bot is in. I need to be able to generate the invite from the command prompt or as a basic function. This is coded in python 3.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use [`guild.create_invite`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=create_invite#discord.abc.GuildChannel.create_invite) inside `on_ready` looping all guilds.

Edit: You have to get a channel to create the invite to in this case you will get the first text channel and create the invite to it.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Logged in as")
    print(bot.user.name)
    print("------")
    print(bot.owner_id)
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        channel = guild.text_channels[0] # get the first channel
        invite = await channel.create_invite(max_uses=1) # make the invite link
        user = bot.get_user(303069538315010058)  # place your ID here
        await user.send(invite.url)  # Send the invite to the use
```

Comment: While your conversion of the invite to a string still technically works as the invite class does have an __str__ handler, I would highly recommend that you use the built-in function to determine the URL as it’s much easier for people to understand what you’re doing and just makes everything cleaner overall.

Comment: You are right, i missed that part. Accepted your edit <3

Comment: Glad I could help and thanks for taking it so well <3

Comment: I tried this but await guild.create_invite(max_uses=1) is not working. It says Guild has no attribute create_invite. What should I do? I tested everything else and it worked fine. Thank you for your help by the way!

Comment: @jmd123 What intents do you have enabled?

Comment: @Abdulaziz I have presence intent and server members intent. It seems that create_invite does not exist for me? Am I missing an import? I have import discord and from discord.ext import commands. I also made sure to do intents.members = True.

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.command()
async def dm(ctx, *argument):
    #creating invite link
    invitelink = await ctx.channel.create_invite(max_uses=100,unique=True)
    #dming it to the person
    await ctx.author.send(invitelink)
```

This works, you would say [prefix]dm

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.